# Convertir un archivo .xls dañado a un archivo .xlsx Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo .xls que está dañado. Cuando se lo abre con Excel dice que puede estar dañado y pregunta que si quiere intentarlo de todas formas, al darle que si el archivo abre normalmente y de allí uno le da en habilitar edición y luego se puede guardar con un nuevo formato .xlsx lo cual arregla el asunto.

El problema es que tengo 1500 de estos archivos.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo con Python?

Ya en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985768/python-converting-corrupt-xls-file se dio una respuesta a este problema, pero en mi caso no funciona:

```
# Changing the data types of all strings in the module at once
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# Used to save the file as excel workbook
# Need to install this library
from xlwt import Workbook
# Used to open to corrupt excel file
import io

filename = r'SALEJAN17.xls'
# Opening the file using 'utf-16' encoding
file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16")
data = file1.readlines()

# Creating a workbook object
xldoc = Workbook()
# Adding a sheet to the workbook object
sheet = xldoc.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
# Iterating and saving the data to sheet
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    # Two things are done here
    # Removeing the '\n' which comes while reading the file using io.open
    # Getting the values after splitting using '\t'
    for j, val in enumerate(row.replace('\n', '').split('\t')):
        sheet.write(i, j, val)

# Saving the file as an excel file
xldoc.save('myexcel.xls')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile('myexcel.xls').parse('Sheet1')
```

Comment: Esa corrección es posible gracias al mismo programa Excel, no creo que haya algún API para esto, la única manera que se me ocurre es automatizar la apertura con el excel y guardado de tus 1500 archivos mediante Python

Comment: Es correcto, ya edité un poco la pregunta pues encontré un usuario que resolvió el problema sin embargo ésta no funciona en mi caso.

Comment: Puedes linkear la respuesta de Jeril en lugar de su página de perfil?

Comment: Por qué no te ha funcionado la solución que adjuntaste?

Comment: Obtengo el siguiente error: UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM.

Comment: Cristiam ten en cuenta que ese código es para Python 2.x. Si estas usando Python  3 habrá que adaptarlo si es posible (ahora mismo no se si  hay versión de xlwt para Py-3). ¿Has probado a abrir los archivos con [OpenPyXL](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) o Pandas a ver que errores te generan (si es que lo hacen)? Habria que saber porqué considera corruptos Excel esos archivos.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, no sabía que era para Python 2.x. Ya lo he intentado con Pandas y genera este error: XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<?xml ve'. Por si acaso los archivos que intento abrir son de esta página: http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=IOTS. Se obtienen exportándolos como un excel.

Comment: cristiam perdón, he revisado el código no tiene problemas en Python 3 en principio. Por lo que comentas o bien los documentos no son UTF-16 o simplemente falta el BOM(byte order mark). Prueba a especificarlo explicitamente usando `utf-16-le` o `utf-16-be` en la codificación al abrir el archivo a ver que te dice. Estoy desde un móvil y no puedo probar nada....

Comment: No hay problema FJSevilla. Utilicé ambas codificaciones y se obtiene el mismo error: Exception: String longer than 32767 characters.